# jquery file upload in mvc while clicking on button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

Here i am using jQuery-File-Upload to upload files. it is working fine. but here file is uploading when we select file, i need to upload file after clicking on submit button.
Please help me how to solve this issue.
i am using the following code.

```
   $('#fileupload').fileupload({


        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/VendorReport/UploadFiles',
        autoUpload: true,
        type: boolen,
        Default:true,
        success: function (msg) {

            alert(msg);

        }
    });


<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]">
<input type="submit" id="btnup" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: set `autoUpload: false,`

Comment: if i keep autoUpload:false it is not allowing file. i need to allow file in file upload and need to work after clicking on submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop auto-upload behavior by setting `autoUpload: false`

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/VendorReport/UploadFiles',
    autoUpload: false,
    type: boolen,
    Default:true,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);

    }
});
```

**EDIT**

To upload file on clicking of button:

*HTML*

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]">
<input type="submit" id="btnup" value="Upload" />
```

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnup").click(function(){
         $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/VendorReport/UploadFiles',
            autoUpload: false,
            type: boolen,
            Default:true,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Or refer its documentation to follow official way--> [How to start uploads with a button click](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#how-to-start-uploads-with-a-button-click)

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/VendorReport/UploadFiles',
    autoUpload: false,
    type: boolen,
    Default:true,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<button/>').text('Click to Upload')
            .appendTo(document.body)
            .click(function () {
                data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                data.submit();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: how to upload file while clicking on submit button..?

Comment: sorry bro, In depth i don't know how this control works in `asp.net`